# Why does adding new image to docx with java cause corruption?

Tags: java, xml, image, relationship, docx

This is kind of a weird question and I don't expect to get a good answer, but I thought I'd try anyway.

I've developed a parser to parse the contents of a DOCX file into HTML and another parser to parse the contents back into docx format. I know there are libraries out there, but in order to keep a lot of the data from being lost I developed my own so information needed in docx wouldn't be lost.

Long story short, I'm having trouble with corruption when the user adds an image to the html.

I've noticed that as the tags in the document.xml are read from top to bottom, the relationship IDs are generated for the document.xml.rels file. So I've made it so when an image is added, it changes the relationship IDs for the rest of the tags as it parses through and creates the document.xml. Likewise I'm re-creating the document.xml.rels file so the relationships have their rIds correspond to the rIds in the document.xml.

After it's saved and I open it, it gives me the message that there's corruption. When I click on details it tells me "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened". It then proceeds to tell me the following:

[image]

I click yes and the document looks completely fine with no information lost. When I save that document and look at the document.xml and document.xml.rels files of both the corrupted docx and the fixed docx I can't find any differences. I'll look through every file inside the file structure with a file comparing tool and don't see any differences.

It makes me think it may be the way I'm zipping up the contents, but I'm not sure.

[Here's](https://youtu.be/B81Xqp2cVcQ) a video that shows why I'm confused. I grab a corrupted file, extract the contents, then re-zip the contents to find the all corruption is gone. There's a video in the description that shows how the files were created.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "There's a video in the description that shows how the files were created.": No, the video shows how you are unzipping  and then zipping again the corrupted file. But how have you **previously** created the corrupted file (the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive)?

Comment: In the video I provided, there's a link in the youtube video description that shows how the files were created.

Comment: "there's a link in the youtube video description that shows how the files were created": No, that link shows a video how you are manually hacking around in the XML of document.xml and document.xml.rels. But, I am sorry, I cannot follow what you are doing there without any descriptions. And I suspect I am not the only one.

Comment: What's important is closer to the end of the video. The problem is, I add the photo to the file structure and zip it up without any corruption and the new image added, but when I delete the image and re-add it again the same way, then zip it up, there's corruption. I hope I'm making sense.